# Book reader Tool integration Drupal 7

Tags: javascript

I Integrated a Book reader tool [Monoscle](http://monocle.inventivelabs.com.au/) written in javascript to get the node.tpl content in the book reader format. I tested it on my php document and it was working great, i am able to get the content from the database in the monoscle tool.

However, im unable to do the same in Drupal i.e.,  i want the **content of node.tpl** in the **TOOL!**

I followed these steps to itegrate the tool.

1. I added JavaScripts and css in Bartic.info file under themes
2. Initiated some JavaScript in node.tpl [Because its not initiating/working when placed in Bartic.info]
3. Placed the rendered content inside the div in node.tpl, which is initiated by JavaScript

   `<div id="rabbit"><?php print render($content); ?></div>`

   Now the thing is am getting the Monoscle framework but not the content - neither from $content nor any paragraph.

Comment: Do you have a link? Are you sure the js call is running correctly? What happens if you place a test paragraph in side the rabbit div instead of render($content)?

Comment: I'm running this thing on localhost, and i placed some content/paragraphs instead of $content, but nothing happens, just the tool is visible minus the content.

Comment: Are you initializing it with `Monocle.Reader('rabbit');`? Open your browser Console Log to see if an error can give you a hint.

Comment: Yes i initalized the script.